# How do you poll AWS Simple Queue Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

The title may be slightly misleading, because I know how to make a call to SQS and receive one or more visible messages. But where do you put the polling code if you're developing a web application that will be deployed to Elastic Beanstalk? I mean, you can't deploy a windows service to EB and you can't make a web application run a poll in the background natively. So what do you do and where do you put it?

Comment: Read about the [Elastic Beanstalk Worker Tier](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html).  It polls the queue and sends the messages to your application via `POST`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mention my platform, but worker tiers aren't support for .Net on Windows server, so it's useless in my instance, but still a valid solution for other environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can receive messages Asynchronously using SQS and you do not need to write code to poll queue. Amazon has library which acts as a wrapper to make SQS JMS compliant. You can register your message listener and function will be called whenever a new message arrives at Queue.

[Using JMS with Amazon SQS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-java-message-service-jms-client.html)

[[Example, Please have a look at Receive Message Asynchronously]](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/getting-started.html)

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like a legitimate solution.